# Merge current main branch into feature branch in git

Tags: git

I am in a feature branch. On main, some files have been added. My local repository doesn't know about it.
So far I switch to main, do a git pull, switch back to my feature branch and do a git merge main.
How can I directly merge the current main with all added files into the feature branch without changing the branch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the remote branch directly, no need to use the **local** `main` branch *at all*:

```
git checkout my-branch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main -m "Pulling changes from main"
```

And it's even shorter if `origin/main` is the upstream of your branch:

```
git checkout my-branch
git pull
```